# Changes in Angular application code not displayed in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

When changing the html-File of an Angular component from a string to another, the browser shows no changes, connected to localhost. It still displays the old string although this string can not be found anymore in the project. When opening the html code from within IntelliJ the changes are displayed.

I tried to disable caching on disk and memory in the browser and tried private mode as well (Firefox). I also tried to delete the dist-folder and rebuilt the project as well as
npm cache clear --force

```
Angular Version:

Angular CLI: 12.2.14
Node: 14.18.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 12.0.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.0.5
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.14
@angular/cli                    12.2.14
@ngtools/webpack                13.0.4
@schematics/angular             12.2.14
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4
```

The angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "landingpage": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/landingpage",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"

            ],
            "scripts": ["src/vendor/jitsi/external_api.js"],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "landingpage:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "landingpage:build:production"
            },
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "landingpage:build:test"
            },
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "landingpage:build:dev"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "landingpage:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "landingpage:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "landingpage:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "landingpage"
}
```

The package.json

```
{
  "name": "landingpage",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-dev": "ng build --configuration=dev",
    "build-test": "ng build --configuration=test --base-href=/viper/",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod --base-href=/viper/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^13.0.4",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "primeflex": "^3.0.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^12.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: add your angular.json and package.json so I can provide a more generic answer.

Comment: I added them, thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running:

```
ng serve --live-reload
```

Or:

```
ng serve --watch=true
```

Comment: well I watched the files. I was looking after a `"watch": false` but you didn't use it which is good.

Comment: When trying again --live-reload did the trick, thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem ng version 13.2.5. but none of the solutions above work for me.

Comment: I need to see the 'angular.json' file. But in latest angular versions `--live-reload` is not needed anymore. @AliShan

Comment: I was super confident that I am changing and viewing the same file. But in reality I was changing one file and viewing the copy of same file . If any one else is facing the same problem than track the file being viewed from routing and compare it with the file being open in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two files with same name in your application and you're changing the one not being used.